# mysql_query not working in newest php version

Tags: php, mysql, version

I am trying to insert data in to MySQL Database, but have been stuck on Data insertion.

I am using Version `3.0.0` of WampServer and PHP `5.6.16`, phpMyAdmin `4.5.2`.

Everything else are ok, I can `UPDATE, DELETE`...Except `INSERT INTO`.

**Code**

```html
<?php 
    $con=@mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
    mysql_select_db('mydb',$con);
    ////////////////////////////////// 
    if(isset($_POST['post_files'])) {  
        $files = $_POST['files']; 
        $title = $_POST['title']; 
        ////////////////////////////////// 
        $query = "INSERT INTO files (`file`, `title`) VALUES ('$files', '$title')";  
        if(mysql_query($query))
        { 
            echo'OK, Data Inserted.'; 
        }
        else
        { 
            echo 'Sorry! Operation failed.';
        }  
    }
    mysql_close(); 
?>
```

These Bunch of codes were working fine in previous PHP versions.

Comment: The `mysql` extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: @NanaPartykar actually the latest official version of PHP is 7, therefore mysql extension is already removed from PHP.

Comment: Have you considered echoing `mysql_error()` instead of `'Sorry!  Operation failed.'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `mysql` use `mysqli` For instance:

- `mysql_connect` will be replaced by `mysqli_connect`
- `mysql_query` will be replaced by `mysqli_query($con, $query)`
- and so on

Note that, for some functions, you may need to check the parameters carefully: Maybe there are some differences here and there -- but not that many, I'd say: both mysql and mysqli are based on the same library (libmysql ; at least for PHP <= 5.2)

For instance :

with mysql, you have to use the `mysql_select_db` once connected, to indicate on which database you want to do your queries
mysqli, on the other side, allows you to specify that database name as the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect`.
Still, there is also a `mysqli_select_db` function that you can use, if you prefer.

For more information read this article :
[PHP MySQL to MySQLi](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html)